# Pandas merge returning empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am merging the following 2 dataframes on a common column:

URL for df_a: `[https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rmymbpomp2b1nd/df_a.csv?dl=0][1]`
URL for df_b: `[https://www.dropbox.com/s/67713f3y8omvuru/df_b.csv?dl=0][1]`

```
pandas.merge(df_a, df_b, on='County')
```

returns an empty dataframe, even though there are common county values in the 2 dataframes. any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counties in `df_b` all have trailing space. You can correct this with

```
df_b.County = [c.strip() for c in df_b.County]
```

The merge works after this.